# Removing file from remote repository only

Tags: git

I've read most of the other questions on this and done the steps as advised there.

`git rm --cached <filename>` worked correctly, but when I go to commit, it says everything is up to date.

Seems like I must be missing something obvious here.  How do I push the removal of this file from the remote repository?

```
Jordan@JBH-LAPTOP /c/sites/SAM3 (master)
$ git rm --cached SAM3/Web.config
rm 'SAM3/Web.config'

Jordan@JBH-LAPTOP /c/sites/SAM3 (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    SAM3/Web.config


Jordan@JBH-LAPTOP /c/sites/SAM3 (master)
$ git commit . -m "Remove the webconfig please"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Jordan@JBH-LAPTOP /c/sites/SAM3 (master)
$ git commit SAM3/Web.config -m "Remove the webconfig please"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: try `git add -u` if you are thinking staging deletions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing `git rm` you need to do `git commit`. Git says that `Everything up-to-date` is because you have not created a commit with this file removed.

For example if you do `git reset --hard` you'll see that your file is back.

In general `git rm` is no different from git add.

> will this override all my commits

No it won't, it will create a new commit with this file removed. Only below steps are enough -

```
git rm #your_files

git commit -m "#your_comments"

git push origin #your_local_branch:#your_remote_branch
```

Comment: Interesting, so it was my `.` that did it?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the `.` does.  I thought it committed all changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rm 

git commit -m -a "Commit stmt"

git push origin <branch name>
```

This should work.